Flutter Media Kit different headers data?
My backend server wants each request for video content has unique id in each request i have achieved it when user select a video i genrate a unique number and send to the server it works, now when user seek the video to different time position which is not available it makes a new request to the server i want that time to replace the headers data with new one.
this is what i have now
 Map<String, String> headers = {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $token',
        ...AppHashingCryptography.getExtraHashedData(),
      };

    
    courseVideoPlayer
        .open(
      Media(
        currentVideo.value!.videoPath,
        httpHeaders: headers,
      ),
      play: true,
    )
        .then((_) {
      // Successfully opened the video
      print('Video opened successfully');
    }).catchError((err) {
      // Handle the error
      print('Error: $err');
    });

token always stays the same but the headersData from cryptography needs to be different but it keep sending the first loaded headers which is not acceptable at serverside.
